# error: Segmentation fault: 11 (in target 'RxSwift' from project 'RxSwift')

Tags: ios, xcode, build, rx-swift, reactive

I have just created my first project in `RxSwift`. The sample project named is `RxSwift` and added below pods in `Podfile` following the [guidelines here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift).

#### Podfile:

```
# Podfile
use_frameworks!

target 'RxSwift' do
    pod 'RxSwift', '~> 5'
    pod 'RxCocoa', '~> 5'
end

# RxTest and RxBlocking make the most sense in the context of unit/integration tests
target 'RxSwiftTests' do
    pod 'RxBlocking', '~> 5'
    pod 'RxTest', '~> 5'
end
```

#### RxSwift - Host App:

I have just added `import RxCocoa` in my `ViewController` (of default sample template) and tried to build. Result is a build error. **What am I missing?**

#### Build Error:

> error: Segmentation fault: 11 (in target 'RxSwift' from project 'RxSwift')

**Details**:

```
0  swift                    0x0000000104e4eeb3 PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 51
1  swift                    0x0000000104e4e686 SignalHandler(int) + 358
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff75877b5d _sigtramp + 29
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 000000000000000000 _sigtramp + 2323154112
4  swift                    0x00000001017645ff swift::SerializedModuleLoaderBase::loadModule(swift::SourceLoc, llvm::ArrayRef<std::__1::pair<swift::Identifier, swift::SourceLoc> >) + 463
5  swift                    0x000000010158a340 swift::performNameBinding(swift::SourceFile&, unsigned int) + 3136
6  swift                    0x0000000100da7c08 swift::CompilerInstance::performSemaUpTo(swift::SourceFile::ASTStage_t) + 3608
7  swift                    0x0000000100a9db6f performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 815
8  swift                    0x0000000100a9a034 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 6820
9  swift                    0x0000000100a275a3 main + 1219
10 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff7568c3d5 start + 1
11 libdyld.dylib            0x000000000000005d start + 2325167241
error: Segmentation fault: 11 (in target 'RxSwift' from project 'RxSwift')
```

---

**Note:** I have not modified anything in host app side. I just imported `RxCocoa` in my `ViewController`. Also when I delete the import statement from the ViewController class, build is succeeding.

Comment: please change your target and project name "RxSwift"

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thanks it resolved the issue. However Xcode/Rx should have handled this type of issues with convenience message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is for an unhandled case by `Xcode` and `RxSwift`. Project target name should not be same as library name i.e. `RxSwift`. Expected Xcode smart enough dealing that case  with appropriate message while installing library. In my case changing project and target name to `MyRxSwift` fixed the issue as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60051420/error-segmentation-fault-11-in-target-rxswift-from-project-rxswift/60079627#comment106205452_60051420) by Karthik.